# How to properly host rational rose real time project in git?

Tags: git, ibm-rational, rational-rose

I'm using rational rose real time (rrrt).

I want to host a project on git but I wonder what about conflict in diagram ? For example, rrrt has the habit of update the number id of the transitions. It has also the habit of changing the order of the methods in the file.
You will agree that it is difficult in this case to easily manage conflicts when a method addition or a change in the state diagram changes a lot of things (not necessarily very useful).

How do you do it?

Thank you in advance.